# Isometric spheres in euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, isometry

I would like to prove that the sphere of radius $R>0$, $S^2(R)\subset \mathbb{R}^3$, with the induced metric is isometric to the sphere with radius $1$, $S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$, furnished with the metric $g(X,Y):=R^2 \cdot \langle X,Y\rangle$. Here the scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the standard metric induced from the euclidean space. Is the following proof correct?

Claim: $$\phi:S^2 \ni p\mapsto R\cdot p\in S^2(R)$$
is an isometry.

The map is a diffeomorphism. I feel comfortable with this part of the proof, therefore I will omit the details.

Since $\langle d\phi X,d\phi Y \rangle=\langle R\cdot X, R\cdot Y \rangle=R^2\langle X,Y \rangle=g(X,Y),$ the map is a Riemannian isometry.

Is the argument correct?:

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that looks right. ${}{}{}{}$